# NodeJS: Uploading local XLSX file using Slack API

Tags: node.js, xlsx, slack-api

I'm currently working on a Slack bot that will send out XLSX file with specific data, for some reason the bot doesn't send anything, could somebody please guide me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import fs from "fs";
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from "form-data";

 form.append(
    "token",
    myToken
  );
  form.append("channels", channelID);
  form.append(
    "file",
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/community-statistics.xlsx"),
    "community-statistics.xlsx"
  );

  try {
    await axios.post("https://slack.com/api/files.upload", form, {
      headers: form.getHeaders(),
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind, I was not using the correct Token, problem solved :)